# How to allow both anonymous and authenticated access to the Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

I have a **Asp.Net Core Razor Pages** web app that has some pages **Azure AD** authenticated and some unauthenticated/anonymous. It works perfectly when I run in the debug mode in Visual Studio. When I publish the same on the Azure Web App I can either make the entire web app **Authenticated or Unauthenticated**. Is there a way to allow both at the same time?
[image]

Comment: As the description in that screen indicates "if you allow unauthenticated requests you'll need your own code". That refers to setting up authorization within your ASP.NET Core project, not using this setting externally

Comment: I agree with @NoahStahl and I assume that you followed [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) to enable azure ad authentication for you web app service. This tutorial is for apps those hasn't integrated authentication in their code. And azure web app provide an easy way for them to enable authentication by azure ad, so you just need to create azure ad app and set it as the authentication app, and also require users to set a redirect url to be the entrance of the app after signing in.

Answer (score 0):

From the azure portal, we can see that azure webapp does not support simultaneous settings. But we can set it from the code, and Noah Stahl and Tiny Wang are correct.

**Phenomenon:**

Create a simple application that does not include login, or simply put an index.html file, we can set it on the portal to perform the third-party login function.

As you can see, you can only choose one, Authenticated or Unauthenticated. And if you choose Authenticated, you can also choose one of the providers. This function is the simplest function in the portal.

## Suggestion:

If you want to achieve multiple third-party logins, you still need to start from the code level so that you don't need to set up on the portal. It should be too simple on the portal.

You can refer below official doc:

[Facebook, Google, and external provider authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[image]

**When you implement it, you can still access other resources in the unlogged state. When you need to log in, all supported third-party buttons will appear on the login page. Click the button to log in.**

*The option setting in the portal is a restriction on the current global access to the entire website.*

[image]